# What Home notifications are "critical" and "time sensitive"?

Tags: notifications, homekit, ios

Since updating to iOS 15 and Watch 15 I've gotten notifications from Home on my Watch in the middle of the night while in Sleep Focus.

I don't want to be woken every time a part of HomeKit goes off line (a regular occurrence since 15) but do still want to receive such notifications in all other Focus modes.

What Home notifications are "critical" and "time sensitive"? Specifically, how do I configure Focus and Notifications so that I still get any motion detection, camera recording, and ideally also any device offline notifications (though I'm willing to forgo the latter) in *all* Focus modes, but *not* be disturbed in the middle of the night when some part of HomeKit goes momentarily offline?

Comment: If home kit or your router is offline, that means you can’t receive a motion alert, correct?

Comment: I've never had the router go offline, if that's what your asking. But HK often thinks components have gone off line (often when they haven't, but I'd still like to know — when I'm not sleeping).

Comment: Are you asking if you can change arbitrary alerts or asking someone to document all the possible combinations? It’s not clear what you want answered to me at least…

Comment: I want to know which categories of Home notifications (e.g. offline component vs. motion detection vs. triggered camera recording) are considered "crtical" and which are considered "time sensitive".